# Checking for a string in two different dataframes and copy the corresponding rows to calculate statistics in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a python code and have for example 2 different DataFrames (the number of dataframes can be more than 2)  as follows:

```
df1 = 
Index    Name      Age     Height  
0        Tom       20      166
1        Bill      27      170
2        Jacob     39      180
3        Vivian    26      155
```

```
df2 = 
Index    Name       Age     Height  
0        Mary       20      166
1        Tom        27      170
2        Bill       39      180
3        Jack       26      155
```

I want to check the names in both the dataframes and if they match add corresponding entries in the columns so that the final result looks like a third dataframe:

```
result =
Index    Name      Age     Height  
0        Tom       47      336
1        Bill      66      350
2        Jacob     39      180
3        Vivian    26      155
4        Mary      20      166
5        Jack      26      155
```

Tom and Bill have 2 entries in 2 dataframes, so their Age and Height get added and others have a single entry, so the original number is displayed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) both the DataFrames then GroupBy name using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```
# Assuming `Index` is not a column. If it's a column
# set it as index using `df.set_index("Index")

out = (
    pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
    .groupby("Name", as_index=False, sort=False)
    .sum()
)

out

#      Name  Age  Height
# 0     Tom   47     336
# 1    Bill   66     350
# 2   Jacob   39     180
# 3  Vivian   26     155
# 4    Mary   20     166
# 5    Jack   26     155
```